# Laravel, PHP で chmod メソッド使用時に Operation not permitted エラーが発生する

Tags: php, laravel

現在Laravelでスクレイピングを実装しているのですが、ローカル環境からステージング環境に移行した際に、`file_put_contents` メソッドについて `failed to open stream: Permission denied` というエラーが出ました。

そこでファイルの書き込み権限を変えようと処理に `chmod` メソッドを加えたところ `chmod(): Operation not permitted` というエラーが出ました。どうすれば解決できますか？

Comment: `chmod` はファイルやディレクトリのアクセス権限を変更する操作ですが、表示されているエラーはファイルに対する適切な権限が無い時に表示されるものです。 / 操作対象のファイルのアクセス権限や所有者、プログラムがどのユーザで実行されているか、辺りを確認してみてください。 / エラーメッセージでこのサイトを検索してもらうと、いくつか似た事例がありますのでそちらも参照してみてください。

Comment: ご丁寧に回答ありがとうございます！適切な権限を加えるためにchmodを使うというのは検討違いなのでしょうか…ユーザー確認してみます！また、サイトで似たような事例も探してみます！

Answer (score 1):

ファイル書き込みするときはfile putする先のディレクトリを以下の通り所有者と権限を変更します。

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/service/approot/(saveDirectory)
chmod 777 /var/www/service/approot/(saveDirectory)
```

(もちろんながら、パーミッション指定やユーザーは若干環境によって変わります。共有サーバーだとftpユーザー名だったり)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。保存先ディレクトリの権限を先に変更しておくということですね。次回以降参考にさせていただきます。